# Define MyEclipse shortcut for VSS plugin operations

Tags: java, version-control, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-sourcesafe, myeclipse

I have MyEclipse Workbench 8.6 for developing my project and Microsoft Visual SourceSafe (VSS) as my source version controller. I define useful shortcuts in Preferences/Keys menu usually but can't define a shortcut for VSS plugin operations. For sample I refresh a class from VSS by following steps:

1. Right click on class and select `team` menu item.
2. Select `Refresh` item.

My question is:

Is there way for doing above scenario by a short key? My real means is : Define shortcuts for VSS operation in MyEclipse.

Comment: Did you upgrade the product? The current version is 10.6.

Comment: I will update as soon ;)

Comment: My projects even didn't compile under 8.6. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Under Preferences\General\Keys you can define bindings. If there's no such a command you should probably write a plug-in. Why didn't you try `Synchronize with repository` or `Team Synchronizing`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I look up  in `keys`, but not found any result for my request.